# Can't get to a javascript console on mobile and can't use usb debugging due to lack of computer any alternatives?

Tags: android, debugging, mobile, console

Pretty much as the title says I can't access developer tools, being on mobile, to look at the browser console, and i can't access a computer to go the USB debugging route does anyone know an alternative and easier way of getting the console errors, that doesn't require much brainpower. I don't want to enable any remote desktop thing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found an ok way to get errors using window.onerror, and nested the window.alert with the error reported as such:

window.onerror = function( message, source, lineno, colno, error ) {
  window.alert( message + ",  " + source + ",  " + lineno + ",  " + colno );
  return true
}